# Encode 2D Array with Freddy (json)

Tags: json, swift, multidimensional-array

Attempting to encode variables, including a 2D array of Int with the JSON framework Freddy. The error I receive is obvious, "Cannot convert value of type '[[Int]]' to expected argument type '[JSON]'", but I am not sure the proper way to accomplish encoding myArray by conforming to Freddy.JSONEncodeable. myArray may not always be the same size, in both dimensions.

```
import UIKit
import Freddy


class MyClass: NSObject, JSONEncodable {

var myArray: [[Int]] = []
var myType:String = ""
var myName:String = ""


public override init() {
    super.init()

    myName = "Freddy"
    myType = "plaid"

    myArray = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 7), count: 7)
    myArray[0] = [0,0,1,1,1,0,0]
    myArray[1] = [0,1,1,1,1,1,0]
    myArray[2] = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
    myArray[3] = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
    myArray[4] = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
    myArray[5] = [0,1,1,1,1,1,0]
    myArray[6] = [0,0,1,1,1,0,0]  
 }

//MARK: JSONEncodable 

public func toJSON() -> JSON {   
        let returnDictionary = JSON.dictionary(["type": .string(self.myType),
                                                "name": .string(self.myName),
                                                "myarray": .array(self.myArray)])
        return returnDictionary
}
```

}